# Cython conditional compilation based on external value given via `setuptools`

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, conditional-compilation

I try to conditionally generate C code from a Cython pyx file. I found in the Cython documentation that I can use `DEF` to define a value and `IF` to conditionally generate code based on a defined value, but how can I set the value from the `setup.py` via `Extension` from `setuptools`.

Thank You

Comment: What you are looking for was shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225187/try-statement-in-cython-for-cimport-for-use-with-mpi4py/26226758#26226758).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for the link.

The interesting flag in the `setup.py` is `cython_compile_time_env`. And to import the `Extension` from Cython.

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Distutils.extension import Extension

ext = Extension(
    name,
    include_dirs=include_dirs,
    cython_compile_time_env=dict(OPENMP=True),
    sources=['test.pyx'])

setup(name=name,
      cmdclass=dict(build_ext=build_ext),
      ext_modules=[ext])
```

And in the `test.pyx`:

```
...
IF OPENMP:
#Do openmp
ELSE:
#No openmp
...
```

Cython conditional statements (`IF...ELSE` above) are documented [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#conditional-statements).

Comment: Here is [the report of this feature being added to Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/81). It's not well-documented. Sometimes one is told to use the keyword `pyrex_compile_time_env` instead of `cython_compile_time_env`. Also worth knowing is that if your setuptools directories can fail to be clean in ways that aren't obvious: so that building again with what you expect would be new compile time variables will just go with the previously cached results. Even `python setup.py clean --all` didn't avoid this. I ended up just `touch`ing my `.pyx` file before each build.

Comment: Relevant to users of the function `cythonize`: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1572

Comment: And example usage of the argument `compile_time_env` of `cythonize`: https://github.com/pywr/pywr/blob/80784dfbe1aa0fc143247f4304c5f5eaa0dd3809/setup.py#L151

Comment: In a more complicated setup, you may want to modify the environment (just a dict) at a later stage when you have more information like this `class custom_build_ext(build_ext): ... def build_extensions(self): self.cython_compile_time_env = {}`