# Conditional importing in "from extern" in cython based on python version

Tags: python, cython, python-c-api

I found that naive conditions in `def extern from ...` blocks are not allowed. For example if I use something like this:

```
from cpython.object cimport PyObject, PyObject_Hash
from cpython.version cimport PY_MAJOR_VERSION, PY_MINOR_VERSION

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3 and PY_MINOR_VERSION >= 5:
        PyObject* _PyDict_GetItem_KnownHash(object mp, object key, Py_hash_t hash)

if not (PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3 and PY_MINOR_VERSION >= 5):
    def _PyDict_GetItem_KnownHash(object mp, object key, Py_hash_t hash):
        return mp[key]

...
```

When trying to `%%cython` this it aborts with the error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cpython.object cimport PyObject, PyObject_Hash
from cpython.version cimport PY_MAJOR_VERSION, PY_MINOR_VERSION


cdef extern from "Python.h":
    if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3 and PY_MINOR_VERSION >= 5:
   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\x\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_ff85a968c2e8e5cee0075b8a4862fc8a.pyx:7:4: Expected an identifier, found 'if'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cpython.object cimport PyObject, PyObject_Hash
from cpython.version cimport PY_MAJOR_VERSION, PY_MINOR_VERSION


cdef extern from "Python.h":
    if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3 and PY_MINOR_VERSION >= 5:
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\x\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_ff85a968c2e8e5cee0075b8a4862fc8a.pyx:7:24: Syntax error in C variable declaration
```

Is there a (working) way to use conditionals when importing functions with cython "from extern" or any alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried to swap the `cdef extern …:` and `if …:` lines?

Comment: @Kay that throws `cdef statement not allowed here`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try statement in Cython for cimport (for use with mpi4py)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225187/try-statement-in-cython-for-cimport-for-use-with-mpi4py)

Comment: See http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#conditional-statements