# cython choose implementation based on Python after cythonize

Tags: python, cython, python-c-api, cythonize

When cython generates a `example.c` files using

```
cython example.pyx
```

this file contains a lot of preprocessor directives to conditionally select different implementations based on conditions like the Python Version. Is there an option to do the same thing inside the cython code.

I did see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225187/try-statement-in-cython-for-cimport-for-use-with-mpi4py), that there is support for conditional compilation of cython to c.
So when I use e.g.

```
IF PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3:
   codepath1
ELSE
   codepath2
```

I have to provide this value when generating the c file:

```
cython src/test.pyx --compile-time-env PY_MAJOR_VERSION=3
```

The generated c file will only contain one of the two codepaths. So it is only compatible with a very specific version of Python, but still contains a lot of code handling other versions. I am searching for a way to generate a c file, that contains both codepaths and selects them using preprocessor directives as well.

```c
...
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
   codepath1
#else
   codepath2
#endif
...
```

So far I did not find a way to achieve this in cython. Is there a way, or do I have to place all version dependent code (e.g. when using the Python C-API) inside a c file instead?

Comment: You can put small blocks of C code inline using `cdef extern from *: """ C code goes here """` (instead of a C file). But I don't think there's really a way to generate the code you want using Cython.

Comment: @DavidW As far as I can see I can not use #if/#else in there either (or a similar functionality using the cython syntax)

Comment: I don't see why not. It just includes the C code verbatim. It isn't really any better than putting the version-dependent code into a C file though - it just saves making an extra file.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your comment. Yes at least this way everything can be placed in a single file